# Javascript: How to extract multiple numbers from a string

Tags: javascript, string

Input:

> "NEW YORK (Reuters) U.S. stock index futures pointed to a slight rebound on Wall Street on Wednesday, with futures for the S&P 500 up 0.34 percent, Dow Jones futures up 0.12 percent and Nasdaq 100 futures up 0.51 percent at 0921 GMT."

Output should be array of all numbers including floats.

A little similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987382/javascript-extracting-number-from-string) but it extracts only one number.

Comment: Regular expressions is the way to go

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this should do it:

```
var text = "NEW YORK (Reuters) U.S. stock index futures pointed to a slight rebound on Wall Street on Wednesday, with futures for the S&P 500 up 0.34 percent, Dow Jones futures up 0.12 percent and Nasdaq 100 futures up 0.51 percent at 0921 GMT.";
console.log(text.match(/(\d[\d\.]*)/g));
```

you can filter out the invalid numbers e.g. `55.55.55` with the following code:

```
var numbers = [];
text.replace(/(\d[\d\.]*)/g, function( x ) { var n = Number(x); if (x == n) { numbers.push(x); }  })
```

Answer (score 6):

This regular expression should work:

```
/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g
```

A test:

```
"NEW YORK (Reuters) U.S. stock index futures pointed to a slight rebound on Wall Street on Wednesday, with futures for the S&P 500 up 0.34 percent, Dow Jones futures up 0.12 percent and Nasdaq 100 futures up 0.51 percent at 0921 GMT.".match(/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g)
```

returns this Array:

```
["500", "0.34", "0.12", "100", "0.51", "0921"]
```

Comment: your solution will fail on: "123.45.67 .56" for e.g.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "fail". It'd return `["123.45", ".67", ".56"]`. "123.45.67" is not a float. You might also say it'd fail on 1 000 000 or 1,000,000 - it just depends on what you need.

Comment: This is the one, I used. Thanks