# Parse HTML source for dollar amounts then set highest amount as var

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I need a JavaScript function that will parse the HTML source of the page from which it is called as an external script, retrieve any dollar amounts in the source, and set the highest dollar amount to a JavaScript variable.

So for instance, if the page contains the text, "Your product is $40.32 and tax is $4.50, your total is $44.82.", the JS should parse those values and set $44.82 to "var total" as the highest amount. Possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible.  What have you tried so far?  You wanna post some code?  Your question shouldn't be theoretical or ask people to code an entire solution for you.

Comment: I'm a PHP developer and have zero JS experience. I'm assuming it uses document.body.innerHTML somehow, but I need to parse the $ values into an array and then use max() probably. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: It is an interesting question.  And you did make it clear what you're looking for... +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks based on the tips I wrote this, which works. Hopefully yours or my solution will help others:

var dochtml = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;

dochtml = dochtml.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

var price_array = new Array;
var pattmatch = /(\$(([0-9]{0,1})?.[0-9]{1,2}))|(\$([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}([,][0-9]{3})*)(.[0-9]{1,2})?)/gi;
price_array = dochtml.match(pattmatch);

if (price_array) {
  for (var i=0; itotal || !total) {
      var total=price_array[i]; 
     } 
  }

document.write(total); 
}

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question here, which demonstrates how to extract numbers from a String:  [Javascript extracting number from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987382/javascript-extracting-number-from-string)

Try this:

```
 // get all content from page
 var content = document.body.innerHTML;

 // create an array of all dollar amounts in the content
 arrayNum = content.match(/\$[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/g);

 // display array of numbers
 console.info(arrayNum);

 var high = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < arrayNum.length; i++) {

     // remove the dollar sign and cast the string to a float
     arrayNum[i] = parseFloat(arrayNum[i].substring(1));

     // get the high value - O(n) operation
     high = ( (arrayNum[i]) > high ) ? arrayNum[i] : high;
 } 

 alert("High value = " high);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the HTML of the current document from the Javascript by grabbing the document's innerHtml, something like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

Then you can pull out all the currency values with a regular expression, something like:

```
((\$(([0-9]{0,1})?\.[0-9]{1,2}))|(\$([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}([,][0-9]{3})*)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?))
```

Just loop through all the matches and every time the current match is greater than the value in total, set total to the current match.

*Disclaimer: That regex was pulled from the community on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and I can't promise you it's 100% fullproof.*