# How to remove £ on span and change value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<span id="lblSellingPrice" class="productHasRef">£11.00</span>
```

Hi i have this code.I like remove this £ and and then multiply the number by 2.50? 
Could this. 
Magnitude sleeping variable is not always 11.

Comment: What are you manipulating this in? PHP or JS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript extracting number from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987382/javascript-extracting-number-from-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `text()` and `replace()` methods for that

```
$('#lblSellingPrice').text(function(i,v){
   return '£'+(parseFloat(v.replace('£',''))*2.50).toFixed(2);
});
```

`toFixed(2)` can be used to set only two decimal points

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/GLX3X/1/)

Comment: the author might want to put the currency mark back (simple modification, but still)

Comment: You pasted the toFixed two times

Answer (score 3):

Get the text of the span and parse it to float after removing the preceding '£' sign. Then you can multiply it by 2.5

```
var price = parseFloat($('#lblSellingPrice').text().substring(1));
var calculationResult = price * 2.5;
```

and if you want to put the currency mark back and format it to a price:

```
var newPrice = '£' + calculationResult.toFixed(2); //toFixed will give you 2 decimals
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/NNqV9/)

```
var num = parseFloat($('#lblSellingPrice').text().substring(1))*2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use replace

```
 var num = $('#lblSellingPrice').text().replace('£', '');
 num = parseFloat(num)*2.5;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/47p4D/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of this question (more or less):

[Javascript extracting number from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987382/javascript-extracting-number-from-string)

although if you don't have commas in your input number you don't need something as complex as the regex, you can just trim your currency marker off with a simple substring:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    text = $("#lblSellingPrice").text().replace("£", ""); //remove the pound sign
    num = parseInt(text); //parse the text into an integer
    alert(num*2.5); //alert the multiplied value
});
```

Or more optimized:

```
parseInt($("#lblSellingPrice").text().replace("£", "")) * 2.5 //parse the text of the span by removing the pound sign and then multiply it by 2.5
```